# how TEST instruction check if number is EVEN or ODD in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

i know that if we do,

```
mov  al, 101b
test al, 100b
```

if the number is **even** it will set the zero flag to 1, and if it is **odd** it resets the flag to 0.

> but what i dont understand is that if it checks the number is even or
>   not why it requires two operands?

it should be like

```
test al
```

I also know that test is similar to and operation its just that it does not change the first operand but question remains the same that

> How it know if number is even or odd by performing AND?

Comment: `mov  al, 101b` `test al, 100b` doesn't test if _AL_ is even or odd. Maybe you mean `mov  al, 101b` `test al, 001b` where the lowest bit is tested.

Comment: related: [assembly check if number is even](//stackoverflow.com/q/49116747) explains why `test al, 1` works.  What are you hoping `test al` would do?  `test al,al` sets flags according to the value in AL, exactly the same as `cmp al,0`. ([\`testl\` eax against eax?](//stackoverflow.com/a/38032818)).  So are you hoping that there's an opcode for `test` with an implicit `1` as the other operand for the AND operation?  There isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i understand it now, that how can test be used to find out if number is even or odd!!!

**You just have to check the least significant bit of the number,**

example:

100**1** is **odd**,

111**0** is **even**

> I want to check if 101 is **even** or **odd**

then i'll do this:

```
mov  al,101b
test al,1b
```

by doing this,

> test will perform **and** operation between 101 and 001

so only the least bit would be checked and if it is **'1'** then number is **odd** otherwise **even**

then finally we can use jump to print if number is even or not:

```
je ; if number is even
```

Answer (score 2):

hard to format this as a comment...

```
mov  al, 101b ; moves the value 101b (5) into al
test al, 100b ; performs a AND between al and the 100b (4) and sets some flags
```

so it should set the Zero Flag to 0, Sign Flag to 0, and Parity Flag to 1...

I think I you want to find if something is odd you would `test al, 1b` then check the zero flag

if you have a byte `0xff AND 0x1` the result will be 0x1 which is non zero... Zero Flag will be 0 (if using `test`) so it indicates oddness.

Comment: The code snippet produces `100b` and will **reset** the parity flag. So `PF=0`.